# Avoiding redundant asynchronous calcluations

Tags: c#, .net, task, async-await

I have some UI code where I have a method that looks like this:

```
    private async Task UpdateStatusAsync()
    {
        //Do stuff on UI thread...

        var result = await Task.Run(DoBunchOfStuffInBackground);

        //Update UI based on result of background processing...
    }
```

The goal is for the UI to update a relatively complex computed status any time a property changes that impacts its state.  There are a few problems here:

1. If I just call this method directly from each place that updates status, the final updated status can be incorrect.  Suppose property A changes and then property B changes.  Even though B calls UpdateStatusAsync after A, sometimes the call-back code (the final UI update) happens in the reverse order.  So: (A -> Update) -> (B -> Update) -> (B Updated) -> (A Updated).  This means that the final UI shows a stale status (reflecting A, but not B).
2. If I always wait for the prior UpdateStatusAsync to complete first (what I'm doing currently), I can wind up performing the expensive state computation many times.  Ideally, I should only have to do the 'last' computation for a series of updates.

What I'm looking for is a clean pattern that accomplishes the following:

1. The final status should never be 'stale' for more than a small time (i.e. I don't want the UI to get out of sync with the underlying state)
2. If multiple update calls occur in a short time (a common use case), I'd prefer to avoid duplicate effort and instead always compute the 'latest' update.
3. Because of several cases where multiple updates may occur in very close proximity (i.e. within milliseconds), it would be handy to have a way to avoid starting the processing for a short while in case other update requests come in.

It seems like this should be a fairly common problem, so I thought I'd ask here if anybody knows a particularly clean way of doing this.

Comment: Isn't this as simple as:  `if (update received) { store info; reset 100ms timer }; if (timer expires) { do calculation };` ?

Comment: @Scott, something like this might work, although it can potentially get pretty stale (I could get updates every 10ms for 1 second, for instance, in which case it would take a full second before the UI status starts updating.)  I'm trying to find a balance between avoiding redundant computation and keeping the UI up to date.

Comment: If you want to keep with this general idea, just add a little bit more complexity: `if (update received && counter < maxStaleCount) { store info; reset timer }; if (timer expires) { counter = 0; do calculation; }.  That gives you a guarantee that you won't get _too_ stale.

Comment: Well, if you're using events (even `INotifyPropertyChanged` events), you could look into [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), it has throttling, composition of event streams and much, much more. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this without using a timer. In general:

```
private async Task UpdateStatusAsync()
{
    //Do stuff on UI thread...

    set update pending flag

    if currently doing background processing
    {
        return
    }

    while update pending
    {
        clear update pending flag
        set background processing flag
        result = await Task.Run(DoBunchOfStuffInBackground);
        //Update UI based on result of background processing...
    }
    clear background processing flag
}
```

I'd have to ponder how exactly to do all that in the context of async/await. I did something similar with `BackgroundWorker` in the past, so I know it's possible.

It should be pretty easy to prevent it from missing updates, but it might do an unnecessary background processing from time to time. But it certainly would eliminate doing 9 unnecessary updates when 10 updates are posted in a short period (probably, it would just do the first and the last).

If you want, you can move the UI update out of the loop. Depends on if you mind seeing intermediate updates.

Comment: I wound up using something similar to this approach (with the addition of a timer to delay starting the task.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most straightforward approach would be to use `CancellationToken` for canceling old status updates and `Task.Delay` for delaying the status update:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancelCurrentUpdate;
private Task currentUpdate;
private async Task UpdateStatusAsync()
{
  //Do stuff on UI thread...

  // Cancel any running update
  if (cancelCurrentUpdate != null)
  {
    cancelCurrentUpdate.Cancel();
    try { await currentUpdate; } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    // or "await Task.WhenAny(currentUpdate);" to avoid the try/catch but have less clear code
  }

  try
  {
    cancelCurrentUpdate = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancelCurrentUpdate.Token;
    currentUpdate = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), token);
      DoBunchOfStuffInBackground(token);
    }, token);

    var result = await currentUpdate;

    //Update UI based on result of background processing...
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}
```

If you're updating *really* fast, though, this kind of approach would create (even) more garbage for the GC *and* this simple approach will always cancel older status updates so if there isn't a "break" in the events the UI may end up lagging way behind.

This level of complexity is where `async` starts to reach its limits. [Reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) would be a better choice if you need anything more complex (such as handling that "break" so you at least get one UI update every so often). Rx is particularly good at dealing with timing.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems I'm on the right track, I'll submit my suggestion.  In very basic pseudo code, it looks like this may do the trick:

```
int counter = 0;

if (update received && counter < MAX_ITERATIONS)
{
     store info;
     reset N_MILLISECOND timer;
}
if (timer expires)
{
    counter = 0;
    do calculation;
}
```

This will let you skip as many calls that are too close to each other as you want, while the counter will make sure that you still keep the UI up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using the approach that Jim Mischel recommended, with a timer added for aggregation of rapid incoming triggers:

```
public sealed class ThrottledTask
    {
        private readonly object _runLock = new object();
        private readonly Func<Task> _runTask;
        private Task _loopTask;
        private int _updatePending;

        public ThrottledTask(Func<Task> runTask)
        {
            _runTask = runTask;
            AggregationPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        }

        public TimeSpan AggregationPeriod { get; private set; }

        public Task Run()
        {
            _updatePending = 1;

            lock (_runLock)
            {
                if (_loopTask == null)
                    _loopTask = RunLoop();

                return _loopTask;
            }
        }

        private async Task RunLoop()
        {
            //Allow some time before we start processing, in case many requests pile up
            await Task.Delay(AggregationPeriod);

            //Continue to process as long as update is still pending
            //This clears flag on each cycle in a thread-safe way
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _updatePending, 0, 1) == 1)
            {
                await _runTask();
            }

            lock (_runLock)
            {
                _loopTask = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This runs updates as fast as possible once the aggregation period has passed, as long as there are still incoming triggers.  The key thing is that this doesn't stack up redundant updates if the triggers occur faster than the calculation and it always makes sure the 'last' trigger gets an update.